# Boolean textInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How do we Boolean TextInput in react native? I tried to use the radio button or checked button but I was unable to send selected data to server-side when the user clicked submit button on the form. If I use the checked button the how do I know that button is checked by user? I'm new to react native, it would be a great help. I'm reading docs of react-native but using boolean text input it was difficult for me to understand. Thank you.

I'm using Picker it would be great to know if there is a better option

```js
<Picker
  selectedValue={status}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue) => setStatus(itemValue)}>
  <Picker.Item label="True" value="True" />
  <Picker.Item label="False" value="False" />
</Picker>;
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. If you could also try including a *running* [Expo Snack](https://expo.io/) we could live debug that would be helpful.

Comment: @DrewReese i have update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Picker

The `label` for the `Picker.Item` is the text that is show to the user, so that always needs to be a `string`.  But for the `value` prop, we can pass the `boolean` values `true` and `false` rather than a `string`.  That's it!

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={status}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
  onValueChange={setStatus}>
  <Picker.Item label="True" value={true} />
  <Picker.Item label="False" value={false} />
</Picker>
```

#### Other Options

A dropdown menu isn't the most intuitive way to select a `true`/`false` value. I would say that a [`Switch`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/switch.html) is the best (though for some reason this isn't rendering right on expo Web).

```
<Switch
  value={status}
  onValueChange={setStatus}
/>
```

Different components have different props, so check the docs to see if the value is a `boolean`, `string`, etc.  For a single [`RadioButton`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html), you use `status={ status ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' }` because it is controlled by the strings `'checked'` and `'unchecked'`.

[Here's a demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lindapaiste/boolean-picker) showing four different options.